# Set default value for checkboxes in Drupal

Tags: forms, checkbox, drupal-7

I'm trying to set a `#default_value` on my D7 form, but it's not working... This is my array:

```
'thema_30fdc789-1453-4efa-93d6-123cab52206e' => 
    array
      '#type' => string 'checkboxes' (length=10)
      '#title' => string 'What kind of fiches??' (length=42)
      '#options' => 
        array
          'create' => string 'New fiches'     (length=13)
          'update' => string 'Updated fiches' (length=13)
          'delete' => string 'Deleted fiches' (length=13)
```

After editing this form with this line:

```
$form['thema_30fdc789-1453-4efa-93d6-123cab52206e']['#default_values']= 
        array('create' => 'Nieuwe fiches', 'update' => 'Update fiches', 'delete' => 'Delete fiches');
```

I get this `var_dump`:

```
 'thema_30fdc789-1453-4efa-93d6-123cab52206e' => 
    array
      '#type' => string 'checkboxes' (length=10)
      '#title' => string 'What kind of fiches??' (length=42)
      '#options' => 
        array
          'create' => string 'Newfiches'      (length=13)
          'update' => string 'Updated fiches' (length=13)
          'delete' => string 'Deleted fiches' (length=13)
      '#default_values' => 
        array
          'create' => string 'Newfiches'      (length=13)
          'update' => string 'Updated fiches' (length=13)
          'delete' => string 'Deleted fiches' (length=13)
```

So, the `hook_form_alter` did his job. Nevertheless, the checkboxes aren't checked on when reloading the page... What do I need to do to make sure they are checked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I found it myself. I needed to adjust the string to this:

```
$form['thema_30fdc789-1453-4efa-93d6-123cab52206e']['#default_value'] = array('create', 'update','delete');
```